# Format string with regex in args in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, format, escaping

I am trying to create a string in Python using the format method, but one of the arguments is a regular expression. I tried:

```
>>> 'foo{}bar'.format('[\s]+')
'foo[\\s]+bar'
```

Because of the escaping, I can't use the result as a `re.search` pattern. Is there a way not to escape it?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you can use it. The ``\\`` is actually 1 ``\``.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that would cause it to match a '\' and a 's' rather than a whitespace.

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/6MyBCs)

Comment: Use a raw string just how you would do it for regex.  The double backslashing is because of how the Python shell prints it.  It wants to indicate to you that this really is a backslash, not a special character.

Comment: `re.findall('foo{}bar'.format('[\s]+'), "hello foo bar" )` works as does  `f = 'foo{}bar'.format('[\s]+');re.findall(f,s)`, how is it not working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you don't need to do anything, because the result is what you expect. `foo[\\s]+bar` is the representation, but not the real value, which is `foo[\s]+bar`. Try this:

```
>> print 'foo{}bar'.format('[\s]+')
# and you will get
>> 'foo[\s]+bar'
```